# SQL Query to retrieve a certain first name

Tags: sql

Write a SQL query to retrieve the loan number, state and city, customer first name for loans that are in the states of CA,TX,FL,NV,NM but exclude the following cities (Dallas, SanFrancisco, Oakland) and only return loans where the customer first name begins with John.

What I attempted:

```
SELECT [LoanNumber], [State], [City], [CustomerFname]
FROM dbo.Loan
WHERE STATE IN ('CA','TX','FL','NV','NM') 
AND CITY NOT IN ('DALLAS','SANFRANCISCO','OAKLAND')
HAVING [CustomerFname] = ' Mr.John'
```

Comment: HAVING is for when you use GROUP BY.

Comment: use this in having clause [CustomerFname]='Mr.John%'. Rest looks good

Comment: As the challenge specifies "begins with John", are you really sure that you should search for " **MR** John"?

Comment: It is good that you attempted a query, but what are your issues with it? An error message usually gives some details (although SQL often isn't very clear, unfortunately). Remember, we don't see your system or have your exact data, we only see what you posted

Comment: If you are looking for names that being with "John", where does the `'Mr.'` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Add wild card entry (%) only at the end of the string to get customers starting with John.

```
SELECT [LoanNumber],[State],[City],[CustomerFname]
    FROM dbo.Loan
    WHERE STATE IN( 'CA','TX','FL','NV','NM') 
    AND CITY NOT IN('DALLAS','SANFRANCISCO','OAKLAND')
    AND [CustomerFname] LIKE 'Mr.John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [LoanNumber],[State],[City],[CustomerFname]
    FROM dbo.Loan
    WHERE STATE IN( 'CA','TX','FL','NV','NM') 
    AND CITY NOT IN('DALLAS','SANFRANCISCO','OAKLAND')
    AND [CustomerFname] LIKE '%Mr.John%'
```

Comment: The requirement is "only return loans where customer first name begins with John." How does a `like` pattern that _starts_ with a wildcard do that?

Comment: The space in your ' Mr.John' would make it not match 'Mr.John'. You could do LIKE 'Mr.John%' or LIKE ' Mr.John%' etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [LoanNumber], [CustomerFname], [City], [State]
FROM [dbo].[Loan]
WHERE [State] IN ('CA','TX','FL','NV','NM') 
AND [City] NOT IN  ('Dallas', 'SanFrancisco', 'Oakland')
AND  [CustomerFname] LIKE '%John%'
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.